# How to place video.js controls below the video without creating a same-sized bar above the video

Tags: css, html5-video, video.js

Setting a height for the video element (using Video.js) causes the video to be centered in the frame (I think).  I want to place the controls at the bottom of the video frame, but with the video itself placed against the top.

The goal is to position the controls so they are not on top of the video itself, but without a bar at the top that's the same height as the control bar.

When the frame is sized to the source, the video is where it's supposed to be and the controls are on top, at the bottom of the frame.  To get them below the video requires adding 2x the control bar height to the frame height, which creates the bar above the video.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: And where is your code? Make a fiddle or something similar to show what you have so far :)

Answer (score 4):

This is one way to do it. Add a class, here `vjs-static-controls`, and set the height to 30px higher than the video since the default control bar height 30px.

```
<video
  id="MY_VIDEO_1"
  class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-static-controls"
  controls
  preload="auto"
  width="720"
  height="330"
  poster="http://www.videojs.com/img/poster.jpg"
  data-setup="{}" />
```

Then you can override the styles that position the video and poster, and handle showing and hiding the control bar:

```
/* Always show control bar */
.video-js.vjs-static-controls .vjs-control-bar {
  display:block;
}

/* Don't fade out controls */
.video-js.vjs-static-controls.vjs-has-started.vjs-user-inactive.vjs-playing .vjs-control-bar {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible; 
}

/* Align poster to top */
.video-js.vjs-static-controls .vjs-poster {
  background-position: 50% 0;
}

/* Override tech height:100% */
.video-js.vjs-static-controls .vjs-tech {
  height: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```